# How to set default colour for bars in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

This seems stupidly trivial but try as I might I cannot seem to find how to set a default colour for bars in chart.js.

My charts is taking its data from an ajax request and the chart is rendering just fine. However neither updating **Chart.defaults.global.defaultColor** nor adding **defaultColor** to the dataset as an option has any effect.

I would very much appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction here.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
async: true,
url: "{{route('stats.monthlyData')}}",
dataType: 'json',
success: function (response) {
    var labels = [];
    var data = [];
    $.each(response, function () {
        labels.push(this.month_name);
        data.push(this.record_count);
    });
    drawChart('# of Records', labels, data);
}
});

function drawChart(label, labels, data){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart");
    //Chart.defaults.global.defaultColor = "#3498db"; Tried this but does not work
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: label,
                data: data,
                //defaultColor: ['#3498db'], Tried this but does not work
                backgroundColor: ['#3498db'], //Only the first bar gets set
                borderColor: [],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

In case it helps anyone, the issue was that I was setting the **backgroundColor** property to an array with only a single entry. If you want to default it for all columns then it should only be set to a string.
Credit to @mp77 for leading me to notice this issue.

Comment: Hey I was having the same problem as you whereby only the first bar with color. How did you solved it?

Comment: remove array [] like
 backgroundColor: '#3498db', //Now it will set this color as default to all the bars

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use `fillColor` property in your `datasets` array like this -
(and instead of `borderColor`, try `strokeColor` like below)

```js
datasets: [{
    label: label,
    data: data,
    fillColor: "rgba(14,72,100,1)", // v2+ uses background color
    strokeColor: "brown",
    borderWidth: 1
}]
```

A full working example can be seen from one of the demos of chartjs [here](http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/Kpager)

Comment: Hi, it seems fillColor no longer works in chart.js 2. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: Brilliant your answer lead me to the answer. I noticed the issue, I was setting the backGroundColor to an array with only one entry rather than a simple string. Thanks a million for your help.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: For reference: in the latest versions the attribute is now "backgroundColor"

Comment: If you want to set 1 default color for the bar then remove array [] like backgroundColor: '#3498db',  [] or array of color will set each bar independently

Answer (score 1):

On the latest version, I used `backgroundColor` instead of `fillColor`

Answer (score 1):

You have used an array of colors. Chart.js can use that, but will then use a color per bar. If you want to have all bars in the same color, don't use an array, but a single value. Like this:

```
backgroundColor: "#33AEEF",
```

If you want each bar to have a different color, use the array instead, like this:

```
backgroundColor: ["#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF", "#33AEEF"],
```

I've also set the border to 0, but that's a personal preference, like this:

`borderWidth: 0,`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer from [Chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/colors.html#default-color-palette):

> If you don't have any preference for colors, you can use the built-in Colors plugin. It will cycle through a palette of seven Chart.js brand colors. All you need is to import and register the plugin:
>
> ```
> import { Colors } from 'chart.js';
> Chart.register(Colors);
> ```