# chart.js v2.80 Default Bar Chart backgroundColor

Tags: javascript, chart.js2

I can't get default bar colors to set in `chart.js` version 2.80 (and 2.72 earlier trial).  I have looked and found this ([How to set default colour for bars in Chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43117395/how-to-set-default-colour-for-bars-in-chart-js)) however it doesn't provide enough information for this to work.

```
Chart.defaults.global.defaultColor = "rgba(51, 102, 255, 0.3)"
Chart.defaults.global.backgroundColor = "rgba(51, 102, 255, 0.3)"
Chart.defaults.global.borderWidth = 0
```

I am assuming the colour (I'm Canadian) of the horizontal bar should be the blue I've assigned.  When set inside the chart instance, the very same way in `data:datasets:backgroundColor`, it works.  I only want one colour for every chart in my site, so it is optimal to set this in a config `.js` file as opposed to manually writing this out all the time.  Very modular.

How can I do this?  Is this a bug?  The `defaults` seem rather straight forward.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the bars on the chart, if so you can use `Chart.defaults.global.elements.rectangle.backgroundColor` as that seems to effect it but seems like a massive hack, but I'd raise this as a issue on their github, imo it should use `Chart.defaults.global.defaultColor`

Comment: Looking at their github they have an issue open for this and recommend [this as a workaround](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4299#issuecomment-346285769)

Comment: OK, so I'm not going insane.  This was something so remedial that I thought I was doing something wrong.